# React memory game

Tags: react.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; import styled from 'styled-components'

const GameArea = styled.div`   height: 200px;   width: 100px;   border: '1px solid black'; `

const Box = styled.div`   width: 50%;   height: 50%;   background-color: ${props => props.color};   text-align: center;   opacity: ${props => (props.isActive ? '50%' : '100%')};   display: inline-block; `

function App() {   const boxColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];   const [moveCount, setMoveCount] = useState(0);   const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false);   const [clicksEnabled, setClicksEnabled] = useState(false);   const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);   const [playerCombination, setPlayerCombination] = useState([]);   const [gameCombination, setGameCombination] = useState([]);   const [numberOfRounds, setNumberOfRounds] = useState(1);   const [boxStates, setBoxStates] = useState([false, false, false, false]);

  useEffect(() => {
       }, []);

  const isPrefix = (largerArray, smallerArray) => {
    return smallerArray.length <= largerArray.length && 
      smallerArray.every((value, index) => value === largerArray[index]);   };

  const isSame = (firstArray, secondArray) => {
    return secondArray.length === firstArray.length && 
      secondArray.every((value, index) => value === firstArray[index]);   };

  const resetStates = () => {
    setClicksEnabled(false);
    setGameStarted(false);
    setPlayerCombination([]);
    setGameCombination([]);
    setNumberOfRounds(1);
    setBoxStates([false, false, false, false]);   }

  useEffect(() => {
    const isCorrect = isPrefix(gameCombination, playerCombination);
    if (isCorrect) {
      console.log('isPrefix')
      console.log(playerCombination)
      console.log(gameCombination)
      const isEqual = isSame(gameCombination, playerCombination)
      if (isEqual && gameCombination.length > 0) {
        console.log('isEqual')
        const isGameEnd = numberOfRounds >= 10 ? true : false;
        
        if (isGameEnd) {
          resetStates();
        } else {
          const rounds = numberOfRounds + 1;
          setNumberOfRounds(rounds);
          const colorCombination = generateCombination(rounds);
          setGameCombination(colorCombination);
          setPlayerCombination([]);
          showGameCombination(colorCombination);
        }
        
      }
    } else {
      console.log('game over')
      console.log(playerCombination)
      console.log(gameCombination)
      setGameOver(true);
      resetStates();
    }   }, [moveCount]);


     const getRandomColor = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxColors.length);
    return boxColors[randomIndex];   }

  function generateCombination(length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, () => getRandomColor());   }


  const startGame = async () => {
    console.log('startGame')
    const numberOfColors = numberOfRounds + 3;
    setNumberOfRounds(numberOfColors);
    const colorCombination = generateCombination(numberOfColors);
    setGameCombination(colorCombination);
    setPlayerCombination([]);
    setGameStarted(true);
    setGameOver(false);
    console.log(numberOfColors)
    console.log(gameCombination)
    await showGameCombination(colorCombination);   }

  const showGameCombination = async (gameCombination) => {
    setClicksEnabled(false);
  
    for (const color of gameCombination) {
      const index = boxColors.indexOf(color);
  
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          clickBox(index, false);
          resolve();
        }, 4000); // Adjust the delay as needed
      });
    }
  
    setClicksEnabled(true);   };

  const clickBox = (index, color) => {
    if (boxStates[index]) {
      return;
    }
    if (color) {
    
      setPlayerCombination([...playerCombination, color]);
      const count = moveCount + 1;
      setMoveCount(count)
    }

    setBoxStates((prevStates) => {

      const newStates = [...prevStates];
      newStates[index] = true;
      return newStates;
    });
  
    setTimeout(() => {

      setBoxStates((prevStates) => {
        const newStates = [...prevStates];
        newStates[index] = false;
        return newStates;
      });
    }, 2000);   };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{gameOver ? 'Game Over' : ''}</div>
      <div>{!gameStarted ? 'Press Start Button' : ''}</div>
      <GameArea isActive={gameStarted}>
      {boxColors.map((color, index) => (
        <Box 
          isActive={boxStates[index]} 
          color={color} 
          disabled={clicksEnabled} 
          onClick={() => {clickBox(index, color)}}
        >
        </Box>
      ))}
      </GameArea>
      <button type="button" disabled={gameStarted} onClick={startGame}>Start</button>
    </div>   ); }

export default App;
```

I wrote this, and I was thinking it could use some improvements like putting some of the logic inside Box for setting the state isActive since it just sets it active for a few second. What I am most concerned about are unnecessary re-renders and performance improvements that could be made.